# Find how many users are using/creating TFS builds

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 server. As an Administrator, I want to see how many users are using/creating TFS builds into tfs 2015 server? Is it possible to get this data from TFS SQL database using query?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to see how many users are using/creating TFS builds into tfs 2015 server?

I am afraid there is no such out of way to get the user who using/creating TFS build.

We could use the REST API [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get the current state of all the pipelines, then determine whether the status of the pipeline is `inprocess`, if so, output the name of the user who uses this pipeline.

Following is my test sample:

```
$connectionToken="$(PAT)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$PipelineUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/Test/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0" 


$Pipelines = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

$PipelinesId = $Pipelines.value.id


ForEach ($Pt in $PipelinesId)

{
    $baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/Test/_apis/build/builds/$($Pt)?api-version=5.1"                   
    $response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
   
    $PipelinesStaus = $($response.status | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)

    
     If("$PipelinesStaus" -eq '"inProgress"'){
     
         $WhoUsingPipeline = $($response.requestedBy.displayName | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)
         Write-Host "People who using builds = $WhoUsingPipeline"
     
         }
}
```

The test result:

[image]